# Rewrite subdomain to folder if exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a web server with multiple projects running. I have assigned some domains to them:

- example.com
- another-example.com
- foo.bar.com

Then, I have created on folder per each project, so I have the following structure:

- /var/www/

  - .htaccess
  - projects/

    - example
    - another-example
    - foo

I want to rewrite the URLs, so when my server is visited from any domain, I do the following:

1. If the domain (or first subdomain, if any) of the `HTTP_HOST` exists in /projects/ folder, rewrite the entire domain to `/projects/<PROJECT_NAME>`
2. If the folder doesn't exist, don't do anything (which means that 404 error page will be shown)

Note that I don't want to have one rewrite per each domain (my current configuration), just one generic rewrite.

Comment: This is a tough htaccess question, Sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:PROJECT_PREPENDED} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^30
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteCond /var/www/projects/%1 -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)
RewriteRule ^ projects/%1%{REQUEST_URI} [E=PROJECT_PREPENDED:1]
```

But I don't like the approach. Why not just name the project folders as the full host name? As shown in your list. It's more flexible for future use. Anyway the above will do it the way you specified.

If you name your project directories as the full host names, it simplifies to:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:PROJECT_PREPENDED} !=1
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !^30
RewriteCond /var/www/projects/%{HTTP_HOST} -d
RewriteRule ^ projects/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [E=PROJECT_PREPENDED:1]
```

And doesn't leave you in a mess if you want to use the same subdomain on two domains, or two different TLDs for same name, or a subdomain the same as the name in another domain.

Comment: Definitely I buy your second option. It worked after replacing `PROJECT_PREPENDED` with `REDIRECT_PROJECT_PREPENDED` at the first RewriteCond.

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary, and the point of that is so the rule only runs once. It has to match what is set in the flags for the rule. I suggest changing that back and we can work out what's going wrong if it doesn't work again.

Comment: Ok, lets try to fix it. My .htaccess is http://pastebin.com/raw/cL286guq.

Comment: So what happens with that? What doesn't work? You should also fix your rules as you're redirecting twice when someone visits `http://www.example.com/`, once to remove the www and then once to redirect to https. Make your first rule redirect to https:// too. Also you should use `R=301` so Google knows it's permanent. `R` is for temporary redirects.

Comment: Oops, just switched to every-https server. It also works without REDIRECT_ prefix. R without 301 was only for debugging purposes, in order to avoid caching issues. I've realised that `example.com/admin/` is ok, but `example.com/admin` (without the trailing slash) redirects to `example.com/projects/example.com/admin/`. Still working on it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok let me know if I can help. You could perhaps upvote my answer if you feel so inclined :)

Comment: I added a test for 'REDIRECT_STATUS' so it won't do anything if a redirect has already been issued by the other rules above it.